# Who coined the term "Inversion of Control Container" and which public container came first?

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I'm interested in finding out how IoC containers out there has evolved over time since *Inversion of Control Container* was coined as an expression of its own, so I'd like to track down the early ones, if possible.

- Who was the first to mention *Inversion of Control Container*?
- Which public IoC container came first?

Comment: Should be community wiki - how do I fix that?

Comment: you can't do it manually anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From "[Origin of the Hollywood Principle](http://www.betaversion.org/~stefano/linotype/news/42/)" (Feb 5th 2004) by Stefano Mazzocchi:

> ...the Inversion of Control paradigm was
>   coined at Xerox PARC where so many
>   other things were invented.

(read the whole article, it's short and sweet).

Stefano also points at the origin of the *term* "Inversion of Control" in [this other article](http://www.betaversion.org/~stefano/linotype/news/38/) (Michael Mattson, 1996)

Comment: Yes, but what about *Inversion of Control **Container***?

Comment: @Johann: Stefano mentions "container" in the second article I linked, in the context of the Avalon project.

Answer (score 1):

Martin Fowler was probably among the first ones in the "modern sense" of it, but he denies to be the one who invented the term. In fact he cites previous uses of the term, even if it was not "a single term" before.

See http://martinfowler.com/bliki/InversionOfControl.html

One of the oldest ones is probably Apache Avalon, which was used as a container in many frameworks like Cocoon back in 2004/2005.